# How exactly do I allocate all this free space to my Arch partition

Tags: arch-linux, partition

I can't really figure out how to allocate the free space on my SSD to my Archlinux partition. Do I have to move the Arch partition to the left in order to expand it? If yes, what is the best way to do so and are there more things I have to be aware of? Gparted on Arch shows this:
[image]

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to move the Arch partition

Yes, partitions can't be resized to the left, so you need to move it to the start of the free space and then resize it. GParted can do that, use the *Partition → Resize/Move* option. This operation can't be done on a mounted filesystem, you need to use a LiveCD. It will take some time, because all data on the partition needs to be moved, but other than that it's not a complicated task with GParted. As always when working with storage, backing up your data is recommended.